# NSJSONSerialization Json Formatting

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

So I have an array I wanna convert to nsdictionary.  My process works great but I would like to add a heading to the json string.

```
NSArray *showarray = [[MMIStore defaultStore] loadAllShows ];
NSMutableArray* jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Show* show in showarray) {
    NSMutableDictionary* showDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [showDictionary setObject:show.showid forKey:@"Showid"];
    [jsonArray addObject:showDictionary];
}  
NSData* nsdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonArrayoptions:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSString* jsonString =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

Below outputs :

```
{[
  {
    "Showid" : "10027"
  },
  {
    "Showid" : "10707"
  },
  {
    "Showid" : "10759"
  }.....

]
```

How do I make it look like this

```
{
    "Shows":[
  {
    "Showid" : "10027"
  },
  {
    "Showid" : "10707"
  },
  {
    "Showid" : "10759"
  }....
]
}
```

Comment: By the way, `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` is not allowed for this method, you are writing, not reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your array into a dictionary with the correct key.

```
NSArray *showarray = [[MMIStore defaultStore] loadAllShows];
NSMutableArray* jsonShowsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Show* show in showarray) {
    NSMutableDictionary* showDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [showDictionary setObject:show.showid forKey:@"Showid"];
    [jsonShowsArray addObject:showDictionary];
}  

NSDictionary* jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonShowsArray 
                                                           forKey:@"Shows"]

NSData* nsdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary 
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableString *jsonString1 = [[@"{Shows:[" stringByAppendingString:jsonString] stringByAppendingString:@"]}"];
```

Since your jsonstring is a string, you can change it.

hope this helps..

EDIT:

```
NSString *jsonString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{"Shows":%@}",jsonString];
```

Comment: You are missing brackets at the end or something. :)  Can I still post a string to a httprequest like [request setHTTPBody:jsonString];

Comment: Intead of tampering with the string, you should probably change the data before JSON serialization. Check my answer.

Comment: What does it hurt to tamper with the string? If you know this is all you need to do, this is less object creation for the same result IMO.

Comment: @ElJay Since the OP wants to use the JSON as the body to a HTTP request, the only way to get the string is `objects` -> `NSData` -> `NSString` -> `(modification)` -> `NSData`. Instead of the direct route `objects` -> `NSData`.

Comment: @KevinKohler why did u change?

Comment: With your answer I had to mess with the string two more times to get the format right.  His answer is more elegant and got me the correctly formatted json in fewer steps.

Comment: Why didn't someone just use NSString stringWithFormat?